# IOS 7 iphone recording app Error: AudioQueueStart failed (-50)

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, titanium

I have built a iphone recording app with titanium for ios 7 and i have noticed a bug that happens when you lock the phone.

When i run the app everything records fine i can close/minimize the app reopen the app all working great the issue occurs when i close the app and lock the phone click top right button.

If i then re-enter my passcode and open the app again and click record i get the following error in xcode and the top red background service bar flicks in then back out again.

And i get this outputted in xcode.

```
Error: couldn't get queue's maximum output packet size (-50)
Error: AudioQueueAllocateBuffer failed (-50)
Error: couldn't get queue's maximum output packet size (-50)
Error: AudioQueueAllocateBuffer failed (-50)
```

I have been told this maybe a issue with apple could this be true???

Here is a video showing the problem at the end when you see the top red bar flash in and out is where i get the errors above and recording fails.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CvlAAlo3yts

Any help please???

Comment: Can you show the code that causes this? Are you running this on a device? Or the simulator?

Comment: Hi Running on the device the code is in javascript unfortunately else i would share as i am using the titanium api here http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/3.0/#!/api/Titanium.Media.AudioRecorder

Comment: Wait, why can you share the code? Otherwise there is no way to help you out.

Comment: Hi Josiah the code is here https://github.com/appcelerator/KitchenSink/blob/master/Resources/ui/handheld/ios/phone/sound_record.js its just from the kitchen sink

Comment: How are you handling the app life cycles when entering the background mode? And also coming out of background mode?

Answer (score 2):

I found the issue! seems like on iOS 7 there is a need to set this also (I assume this is only practically therefore it's hard to find, isn't written anywhere). Just add this code before calling any AudioQueue function:

```
AudioSessionInitialize(NULL,
                       NULL,
                       nil,
                       ( void *)(self)
                       );

UInt32 sessionCategory = kAudioSessionCategory_PlayAndRecord;
AudioSessionSetProperty(kAudioSessionProperty_AudioCategory,
                        sizeof(sessionCategory),
                        &sessionCategory
                        );

AudioSessionSetActive(true);
```

Comment: Hi mitul thanks for this i am using Titanium so i need to go into the ios sdk into phone and classes find every audio class where that instance appears and add the code?

Answer (score 2):

The answer from user3278923 solved the problem but here is the code for Obj-C:

```
AVAudioSession *session = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
NSError * error;
[session setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryRecord error:&error];
[session setActive:YES error:nil];
```

After recording:

```
AVAudioSession *session = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
[session setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryAmbient error:nil];
[session setActive:NO withOptions:AVAudioSessionSetActiveOptionNotifyOthersOnDeactivation error:nil];e
```

Answer (score 0):

For swift:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avaudiosession

```
let audioSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
        do {
            try audioSession.setActive(true)
            try audioSession.setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback)
        } catch {
            print("Setting category to AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback failed.")
        }
```